# Screenlets change position after restart

Tags: screenlets

I have a problem with my screenlets. They change position on the screen after I restart the computer. This is a known bug according to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenlets/+bug/885322

However a temporary workaround could be to delay the startup of the screenlets to avoid this.

Now I wonder: How do I modify the ~/.config/autostart/xxx.desktop the best way to atchive this.

There is a comment in the bug report about Exec sleep 5 something, but I dont really understand how to write this exactly in the file.

Is there any otherway to solve this?

Using Ubuntu 11.10 and screenlets 0.1.5.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in Screenlets revision 742 (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~screenlets-dev/screenlets/trunk/revision/742). If you install Screenlets from Dev PPA, you shouldn't have this problem any more.

To enable Development versions PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```